# Angular Caching Made simple through interceptor but not for every request, just through a boolean

Tags: angular, caching

> Want to cache requests through interceptor but not for every requests.
>   I need a flag to want to be able to cache or not

Answer (score 3):

Implement Caching in Angular with interceptor only for a few requests & not every request conditionally through a boolean.

I have been checking for online solutions about caching only few requests and not all. Sadly there's not any apt solution for this purpose.
Hence I decided to write one very simple Caching methodology to cache specific requests.

This can be done by below:

Create a cache.interceptor & cache.service like below and add it to the providers of app.module like so:

```typescript
providers:[
CacheService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CachingInterceptor, multi: true }]
```

CachingInterceptor code: The interceptor will only cache requests when it sees a particular header('cache-response') set by your services that make the http call.

```typescript
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Add the service we created in Step 1
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';

@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private readonly cacheService: CacheService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Don't cache if it's not a GET request
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    // delete cache if no header is set by service's method
    if (!req.headers.get('cache-response')) {
      if (this.cacheService.cacheMap.get(req.urlWithParams)) {
        this.cacheService.cacheMap.delete(req.urlWithParams);
      }

      return next.handle(req);
    }

    // Checked if there is cached data for this URI
    const cachedResponse = this.cacheService.getFromCache(req);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      // In case of parallel requests to same URI,
      // return the request already in progress
      // otherwise return the last cached data
      return (cachedResponse instanceof Observable) ? cachedResponse : of(cachedResponse.clone());
    }

    // If the request of going through for first time
    // then let the request proceed and cache the response
    return next.handle(req)
        .pipe(tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                this.cacheService.addToCache(req, event);
            }
        }));
  }
}
```

CacheService Code: This service is used to add/get from cache.

```typescript
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CacheService  {
  cacheMap = new Map<any, any>(null);

  getFromCache(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any> | undefined {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;
    const cached = this.cacheMap.get(url);

    if (!cached) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return (this.cacheMap.get(url)).response;
  }

  addToCache(req: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpResponse<any>): void {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;
    const entry = { url, response, addedTime: Date.now() };
    this.cacheMap.set(url, entry);
  }
}
```

In your services:

```typescript
getMethod(int param1, cache = false): any {
    let headers: HttpHeaders;
    if (cache) {
      headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'cache-response': 'true' });
    }

    return this.http.get(
      'http://apiUrl',
      { headers }
    );
  }
```

And thats it. You have an interceptor that cache's only requests that have a header set.