# Cache results of API calls inside Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, caching, electron

I've got a desktop application I'm writing using Electron to encapsulate and serve Angular files. Electron just launches a chrome web-browser which loads the .js files and executes the Angular code, and then makes callbacks to Electron to manipulate local files.

The Angular side makes several calls to a public API that I don't own to retrieve metadata about the files the user wants to operate on. This API serves content that only gets updated every 24 hours or so, but the x-cache headers only seem to last a few seconds, even though the data rarely changes. This means my app is potentially making lots of unnecessary requests to a rate-limited API.

I would like to save the response of the API calls *somewhere*, preferably on the Node/Electron side of things, (but happily on the Angular side too if that's the only option), and return that data instead of making calls to a rate-limited API, but I can't figure out how to go about doing this. It seems like I'd need some kind of middleware/proxy involved, but all of my searches haven't turned up what I'm looking for.

How can I cache http requests in this application when the browser is what ends up making them?

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason I wanted to do this on the Electron side is that I wanted the cache to persist between runs of the application. In thinking about it a bit more I realized that was completely unnecessary since the browser has multiple ways of persisting data.

My solution utilized a modified version of the HttpInterceptor and CacheService [found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590450/angular-caching-made-simple-through-interceptor-but-not-for-every-request-just) but persisting the data to localStorage.

http-interceptor.service.ts:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly cacheService: CacheService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        if(req.method !== 'GET') {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
        const cachedResponse: HttpResponse<any> = this.cacheService.get(req);
        if (cachedResponse) {
            const response = new HttpResponse({ body: cachedResponse });
            return of(response);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req)
                .pipe(tap(stateEvent => {
                    if (stateEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        this.cacheService.set(req, stateEvent.clone());
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

cache.service.ts - To ensure responsiveness as the cache size increases, I only load the values from localStorage when the cache is init'd, and otherwise just read from the `map` which should be a duplicate of the serialized data in localStorage. Still need to write to localStorage after every `set` call to ensure things are kept in sync. Cache entries expire every 12 hours and are removed to keep localStorage memory low. This could be done on a long `setInterval` if your app is going to be open for long periods of time.

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const LOCAL_CACHE_KEY = 'localCache';
const STALE_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12; // 12 hours

@Injectable()
export class CacheService {
    cacheMap: Map<string, any>;

    constructor() {
        const map = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_CACHE_KEY);
        if (map) {
            this.cacheMap = new Map(JSON.parse(map));
        } else {
            this.cacheMap = new Map(null);
        }
        this.cacheMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            if (Date.now() - value.addedTime > STALE_TIME) {
                this.cacheMap.delete(key);
            }
        });
        this.saveCacheMap();
    }

    get(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any> | undefined {
        const cached = this.cacheMap.get(req.urlWithParams);

        if (!cached || Date.now() - cached.addedTime > STALE_TIME) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return cached.data;
    }

    set(req: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpResponse<any>): void {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const entry = { data: response.body, addedTime: Date.now() };
            this.cacheMap.set(req.urlWithParams, entry);
            this.saveCacheMap();
        }
    }

    private saveCacheMap(): void {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_CACHE_KEY, JSON.stringify([...this.cacheMap]));
    }
}
```

The only other big change from the linked answer is that I don't store the entire response in the Map, just the `body`. When loading from localStorage the `response.clone()` method was lost so storing the whole response didn't make sense, and this allows us to save a little storage space. This does require creating a new HttpResponse in the CacheInterceptor though.

Comment: How did you stringify here `JSON.stringify([...this.cacheMap])`? it is returning an empty array for me, so when I try to reload it is always an empty Map

Comment: @peterpie If it's returning an empty array, then your map is probably empty for some reason. Test it yourself like so: `a = new Map([['one', 1], ['two', 2]]);` then `JSON.stringify([...a])` => `'[["one",1],["two",2]]'` and then you can init a new map with `b = new Map(JSON.parse('[["one",1],["two",2]]'))`